# cannot import name RequestsHttpConnection from elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, request

RequestsHttpConnection was working fine until I had to reinstall Anaconda which is now using Python3.9. Form just trying to import RequestsHttpConnection. I got error below.

`from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection`

Error: cannot import name 'RequestsHttpConnection' from 'elasticsearch' (\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch_*init*_.py)

I have elasticsearch-8.0.0 installed and also have requests installed.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: this import works in 7.13.4. Maybe you should check in documentation if they didn't move `RequestsHttpConnection` to some submodule.

Comment: see GitHub for elasticsearch-py - there is [issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/issues/1778). Someone else had the same problem. Maybe this way you can get help. I try to find `RequestsHttpConnection` in documentationa and I found in 7.x but not in 8.0

Comment: Hi Furas can you please share the documentation link for 7.x and 8.-0? Thanks

Comment: if you visit [issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/issues/1778) and click at top [elasticsearch-py](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py) then you will have source code for `elasticsearch-py`. On right side (below `About`) you will have link to page [ela.st/es-python](https://ela.st/es-python) and there is documentation for `Elasticsearch Python Client`. It is documentation for 7.x. And there is text `Python Client: 7.16 (current)` which is a dropdown menu with link to [8.0](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/python-api/8.0/index.html)

Comment: BTW: in documentation in top right corner of you have icon `magnifier` to search in documentation.

Comment: but better documentation I found using Google: [Python Elasticsearch Client](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v8.0.0/index.html), At the bottom you can see version as green text - and you can use it to change version. [RequestsHttpConnection](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v7.17.0/transports.html?highlight=RequestsHttpConnection#requestshttpconnection) in 7.17.0 - if I try change version to 8.0.0 then shows message `SORRY This page does not exist yet.`

Comment: They mention `RequestsHttpNode` from `elastic_transport` package in [this issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/issues/1778), but I haven't yet found a good example of an alternate approach. The use of the deprecated RequestsHttpConnection is still shown in the [AWS python samples for open search](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/request-signing.html#request-signing-python)

Answer (score 25):

This thing is deprecated in versions 8 and above.

```
pip uninstall elasticsearch
pip install elasticsearch==7.13.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working in ES 8.3.0 with SSL connection and Python ES client 7.13.4

```
from elasticsearch import RequestsHttpConnection  
es = Elasticsearch(
    ['localhost'],
    http_auth=('elastic', 'put-it-here'),
    scheme="https",
    port=9200,
    ssl_context=context,
    use_ssl=True,
    verify_certs=False,
    connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection,
)

print(es.info())
res = es.search(index="index-name", body={"query": {"match_all": {}}})

print(res['hits']['total'])
```

and with 8.8.0:

```
es = Elasticsearch(
    ['https://localhost:9200'],
    timeout=1000,
    basic_auth=('elastic', '<>'),
    verify_certs=False
)
```